# Add decimal digits in Assembly Programming 8086

Tags: assembly, decimal, addition, x86-16

Is there any way to ADD two decimal digits in Assembly Programming 8086 ?

This is what i'm trying:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.code

main proc


mov ah,1
Int 21h

mov bl, al

Int 21h
mov cl, al

ADD bl, cl

mov ah, 2
mov dl, bl
Int 21h


mov ah, 4ch
Int 21h

main endp

end main
```

But the result is in `ASCII`, I want it in `decimal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert from ASCII to decimal value just subtract the ASCII value of the `0` character (48 in decimal), then do your math, and convert back by adding back the value of `0`.

Comment: Thank you :) worked perfectly. I think i should learn more about character mapping.